# Use Primary key or Guid as name of images

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a small cms that my friend written a while ago.

There is this page that the user can upload an image and display it in his profile. I wonder what is the best way to save this image. in this cms it's goes like this: first the entity being save to database and after getting it's primary key, the image being upload to the server with something like `Image-{PrimaryKey}.jpg` then hits the database again to update the same entity with the full name of the image.
So here is part of his code:

In controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<bool> Add([Bind(Include = "IdLanguage,Title,Address,Description,IdLinksCategory")]TblLinks tblLinks, string coverPath, string coverBase64)
    {
        try
        {
            tblLinks.IdUser = await _permissionService.GetCurrentIdUser();
            tblLinks.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;

            await _linkService.Add(tblLinks);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(coverPath))
            {
                byte[] fileByte = _utilityService.GetByteFromBase64String(coverBase64);

                var fileType = Path.GetExtension(coverPath);
                var fileName = string.Format("Link-{0}{1}", tblLinks.IdLink, fileType);
                var fileMapPath = fileName.GetLinkMapPath();

                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileMapPath, fileByte);

                tblLinks.ImageName = fileName;
                await _linkService.Edit(tblLinks);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And service layer:

```
    public async Task<TblLinks> Add(TblLinks links)
    {
        _eTblLinks.Add(links);
        await _uow.SaveChangesAsync();
        _cacheUpdateService.Links();
        return links;
    }

    public async Task Edit(TblLinks links)
    {
        var query = await (from k in _eTblLinks
            where k.IdLink == links.IdLink
            select k).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        query.Title = links.Title;
        query.Address = links.Address;
        query.Description = links.Description;
        query.IdLinksCategory = links.IdLinksCategory;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(links.ImageName))
            query.ImageName = links.ImageName;

        _uow.MarkAsChanged(query);
        await _uow.SaveChangesAsync();
        _cacheUpdateService.Links();
    }
```

What i have in mine and did in some of my work is that i'm using a guid key as the name of my image, and upload it to the server, than use this guid key with the rest of my entity and save then in database at once.

So which way is better? mine or his?

Comment: Just to note, logic in controller goes against MVC's separation of concerns.

Comment: @Dane, So the part that belong to upload an image should be in service layer, right?

Comment: That's my understanding of MVC, although I'm no expert. It just helps to split things out so you can maintain your app easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The both valid and I don't see one being better than the other (apart from a second write in the DB), assuming that in your solution you store the image guid/filename as a property of the entity and not using it as the entity key as well.

Comment: That second write to the database that make me wonder if it's a good approach or not.

Comment: It all depends on your app load, but it shouldn't make much difference on performance, so I would give priority to the one that looks/feels simple and cleaner from the code point of view.